# Insert multiple many to many relationship

Tags: mysql, rest, stored-procedures, many-to-many

I have a typical many-to-many relationship involving 3 tables:

- `user (id, name)`
- `product (id, name, current_price, image, url)`
- `user_product_mapping (user_id, product_id, my_purchase_price)`.

Note that the mapping table has an extra column `my_purchase_price`, as user can specify his own price.

I am building an API that allows bulk insert, e.g.

```
curl -d '{"products": [\
      {"image":"http://example.com/images/testproduct", "name":"testproduct", "url":"http://example.com/products/test", "current_price":50, "my_purchase_price":40},\
      {"image":"http://example.com/images/testproduct2","name":"testproduct2","url":"http://example.com/products/test2","current_price":100,"my_purchase_price":80} \
  ]}' \
  -X POST http://example.com/users/1/products  -H "Content-Type: application/json"
```

In this case, the user ID is 1 and there are 2 products to insert, with their price at 50, 100 respectively, and the user's specified price at 40, 80 respectively.

My question is: how can I effectively insert the data into the 3 tables (creating a user entry if none exists)? I would not want to insert 1 by 1. Hope I can insert them just in a sproc.

The problem is that I don't want duplicates in `product`, `user`, and `product_user_mapping` tables. So if there is already such products in product table (URL is a unique key), then I will just update their prices. If there is already mappings in `product_user_mapping` table, then only my_purchase_price will be updated. I basically would need 2 insert if not exist and update on duplicates, however the second insert update need to know the IDs of the first insert update and I cannot find an effective way to update `my_purchase_price` during second insert/update. To make things more interesting, the API actually allows user to specify the user's name as well, meaning if user 1 does not exist in the user table, I will create an entry for user 1 in user table as well.

I purposely do not use the URL as the primary key in product table, as I think using the URL as a primary key is a bad idea in general (is it?). I have tried several ways, but none of them to my satisfaction:

Method 1:

- `INSERT INTO product ON DUPLICATE KEY (url) UPDATE price, image`
- Get all ids of the previously inserted/updated product ids.
- `INSERT INTO user_product_mapping ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE my_purchase_price`.

Method 2:

```
INSERT INTO product ON DUPLICATE KEY (url) UPDATE price, image;

DELETE FROM user_product_mapping 
  WHERE user_id=1 
  AND product_id NOT IN (
    SELECT product id 
      FROM product 
      WHERE url NOT IN (the urls passed from api)
  );

INSERT INTO user_product_mapping;
```

I seem to have write at least 3 insert-update statements and may need a cursor as well. I have a feeling that I might have over complicated things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case someone comes across the same issue, my solution is to make the URL the primary key in the product table (not sure whether this is a good idea). Thus before I start all the insert operations, I know all the keys I have before hand. I then issue two insert-update-on-duplicate queries (note this step can be done in one SQL statement):

```
INSERT INTO product (url, name, image, current_price)
  VALUES
('http://example.com/product/test', 'testproduct', 'http://example.com/images/testproduct', 10)
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
    url=VALUES(url), 
    image=VALUES(image), 
    current_price=VALUES(current_price);

INSERT INTO user_product (user_id, product_url, my_purchase_price)
  VALUES
(1, 'http://example.com/products/test', 8)
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
  my_price=VALUES(my_price);
```

Remember to set `user_id` and `url` as composite primary key for the mapping table in order for the `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` clause to apply

```
ALTER TABLE user_product ADD PRIMARY KEY (user_device_id, product_url);
```